# How to change spreadsheet to US (ThisWorkbook) from German (DieseArbeitsmappe)?

Tags: excel, vba, internationalization

Our company has a lot of workbooks that were originally saved in German. Therefore, there is no `ThisWorkbook` variable. Instead it's called `DieseArbeitsmappe`. Using `ThisWorkbook` in code results in VBA an error.

I tried renaming `DieseArbeitsmappe` to `ThisWorkbook` with the code below.

```
Private Sub RenameThisWorkbookToEnglish()
  Dim TmpWorkbook As Object

  On Error Resume Next
  'Was this saved in German?
  Set TmpWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("DieseArbeitsmappe")

  If err.Number = 0 Then
    Debug.Print ("German Workbook.")
    TmpWorkbook.Module.CodeName = "ThisWorkbook"
    TmpWorkbook.Name = "ThisWorkBook"
    TmpWorkbook.CodeName = "This Workbook"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  On Error GoTo -1
End Sub

Function ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad() As Boolean
  On Error GoTo ErrLabel
  ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad = Not (ThisWorkbook.CodeName = "ThisWorkbook")
  Exit Function
ErrLabel:
  ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad = True
End Function
```

I called this code in a `Private Sub Auto_Open()`

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()
  RenameThisWorkbookToEnglish

  If ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad Then
    Debug.Print ("Workbook Is Bad.")
  End If
End Sub
```

This code reports as bad. The VBE shows a `ThisWorkbook` module, but its name is still `DieseArbeitsmappe`.

Even though the `Debug.Print` in the `Auto_Open` reports bad, a later button click function that uses `ThisWorkbook` is good. Then saving results in multiple ThisWorkbooks (i.e. `ThisWorkbook`, `ThisWorkbook1`).

So it kind of works, but not really.

Other notes: I only have English installed on my machine. I do not have access to all of the spreadsheets, but am writing VBA that will be put in them.

Main Question: How to change the localization or ??? to make `ThisWorkbook` a valid variable?

Comment: `Diese Arbeitsmappe` is the german name, nothing else. With `ThisWorkbook` you always refer to the workbook, the codee is running in . There is no codename for the workbook.

Comment: Ok, that helped. I was having issues with multiple `ThisWorkbook` objects. That's why I created `ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad`. Tracked it to an apparently errant call to `Application.Volatile` so then I put in the check for the future. I'm going to redo my `ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad` because it looks like it has a false positive for German workbooks. They're not corrupt as in having multiple `ThisWorkbook` objects, but they also don't have a `ThisWorkbook.CodeName = "ThisWorkbook"`. It does look like the `ThisWorkbook` variable is available which was my main concern. Thanks.

Comment: >>There is no codename for the workbook. There does seem to be a codename. `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.CodeName` returns `DieseArbeitsmappe`. I really don't care what to check, just that `ThisWorkbook` variable is valid.

Comment: Ah, right, there is indeed a [codename property](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.codename) for the workbook

Comment: But anyway [ThisWorkbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.application.thisworkbook) should always work.

Comment: Agreed. `ThisWorkbook` _should_ always work. In cases where the workbook is corrupt (like the link in my answer), accessing `ThisWorkbook` definitely causes an error. My code jumped right to the error label when stepping through `If ThisWorkbook.Name <> "" Then` code. During testing a corrupt workbook, I found `ThisWorkbook1` replaced `ThisWorkbook`. Strange situation, but tough to nail down. Then I put in a check that didn't work because I hadn't anticipated workbooks that started in Germany. :-) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Storax, I found my error.

As noted in the comments, I was receiving a false positive from `ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad` on the line `ThisWorkbook.CodeName = "ThisWorkbook"` when `ThisWorkbook.CodeName` was `DieseArbeitsmappe`.

I rewrote `ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad` (below) and tested on a corrupt workbook (i.e. a workbook with `ThisWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook1` like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1048265/remove-multiple-thisworkbook-modules-from-excel-vba-editor)). The corrupted workbook did report an error correctly.

Problem solved.

```
Function ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad() As Boolean
  On Error GoTo ErrLabel

  'Dummy call just to test if ThisWorkbook creates error.
  If ThisWorkbook.Name <> "" Then
  End If

  'Made it here, there is no error and ThisWorkbook is valid.
   ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad = False

   Exit Function
ErrLabel:
  ErrorIsThisWorkBookBad = True
End Function
```